Dynamically Generate Target in Matrix Using DAX
I have a Matrix visual in Power BI where I'm attempting to count various values by categories and sum them up as you +/- through:

The issue comes where there is no value within that date range, so for example on 3/03/2024:

Note how it totals up to 18, and not 24. That is because the 0 count actually consists of no data/rows for that particular date.
My Target measure is as follows:
 Target = 

  var target = 6

  var working = SUMX(SUMMARIZE(TableName,AllVisits[Person]),target)

  return if (working = BLANK(), target, working)

What do I need to change in the measure to have the Target be counted all the way up the tree structure?
Here's a sample pbix file:
https://file.io/sBwzI0uiApXo

Can you share a .pbix?

@davidebacci - that would be really difficult due to the data :(

@davidebacci - I've just uploaded a .pbix :)

I'll remove my answer to encourage others to have a go. Here was my note: I see the totals not adding. This is the issue with not having a proper star schema. I would also be tempted to have hard data for your targets rather than generated dynamically. I have to leave now but if I get time later, I'll take another look. Realistically,you're probably best remodelling the data.

Your data looks strange. In the full sample data, Leader 3 and Leader 8 belong to Team 1 and Team 2. Is this correct or should they only belong to a single team?

@davidebacci - yes that is possible as someone can span multiple areas and report to different people for work done in that area.

@davidebacci - I've just updated the pbix on the original post above - no duplicates across teams now.

Yes, but which statement is true as it has a big impact on your data model. Can a Leader belong to multiple teams? Can a Housing Officer belong to multiple Leaders and Hubs?

No they can't, 1 person to 1 team. It was my mistake with the sample data.

Can you try the following measure:
Target = 
    var people = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(AllVisits,AllVisits[Hub], AllVisits[Team Leader], AllVisits[Housing Officer]), 
        REMOVEFILTERS(DimDate)
    )
    var t = GENERATE(people, VALUES(DimDate[WeekStartDate]))
    return  SUMX(t, 6)


Thanks so much @davidebacci - appreciate you sticking with it :)
